The method '[]' was called on null. Flutter weather app
I have some error:
I/flutter (30216): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (30216): Receiver: null
I/flutter (30216): Tried calling: [](0)

There is my main.dart code:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/models/additionalWeatherData.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/models/geocode.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

import '../models/dailyWeather.dart';
import '../models/hourlyWeather.dart';
import '../models/weather.dart';

class WeatherProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String apiKey = '744b94562476e3686d8944d72c0bb1f2';
  late Weather weather;
  late AdditionalWeatherData additionalWeatherData;
  LatLng? currentLocation;
  List<HourlyWeather> hourlyWeather = [];
  List<DailyWeather> dailyWeather = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isRequestError = false;
  bool isSearchError = false;
  bool isLocationserviceEnabled = false;
  LocationPermission? locationPermission;
  bool isCelsius = true;

  String get measurementUnit => isCelsius ? '°C' : '°F';

  Future<Position?> requestLocation(BuildContext context) async {
    isLocationserviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    notifyListeners();

    if (!isLocationserviceEnabled) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Location service disabled')),
      );
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    locationPermission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      locationPermission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Permission denied'),
        ));
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, Please enable manually from app settings',
        ),
      ));
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  Future<void> getWeatherData(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool notify = false,
  }) async {
    isLoading = true;
    isRequestError = false;
    isSearchError = false;
    if (notify) notifyListeners();

    Position? locData = await requestLocation(context);

    if (locData == null) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }

    try {
      currentLocation = LatLng(locData.latitude, locData.longitude);
      await getCurrentWeather(currentLocation!);
      await getDailyWeather(currentLocation!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      isRequestError = true;
    } finally {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentWeather(LatLng location) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&units=metric&appid=$apiKey',
    );
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      weather = Weather.fromJson(extractedData);
      print('Fetched Weather for: ${weather.city}/${weather.countryCode}');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      isLoading = false;
      this.isRequestError = true;
    }
  }

  Future<void> getDailyWeather(LatLng location) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    Uri dailyUrl = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&units=metric&exclude=minutely,current&appid=$apiKey',
    );
    try {
      final response = await http.get(dailyUrl);
      final dailyData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      additionalWeatherData = AdditionalWeatherData.fromJson(dailyData);
      List dailyList = dailyData['daily'];
      List hourlyList = dailyData['hourly'];
      hourlyWeather = hourlyList
          .map((item) => HourlyWeather.fromJson(item))
          .toList()
          .take(24)
          .toList();
      dailyWeather =
          dailyList.map((item) => DailyWeather.fromDailyJson(item)).toList();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      isLoading = false;
      this.isRequestError = true;
    }
  }

  Future<GeocodeData?> locationToLatLng(String location) async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=$location&limit=5&appid=$apiKey',
      );
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) return null;
      return GeocodeData.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body)[0] as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> searchWeather(String location) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    isRequestError = false;
    print('search');
    try {
      GeocodeData? geocodeData;
      geocodeData = await locationToLatLng(location);
      if (geocodeData == null) throw Exception('Unable to Find Location');
      await getCurrentWeather(geocodeData.latLng);
      await getDailyWeather(geocodeData.latLng);
      // replace location name with data from geocode
      // because data from certain lat long might return local area name
      weather.city = geocodeData.name;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      isSearchError = true;
    } finally {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void switchTempUnit() {
    isCelsius = !isCelsius;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


I've tried to find solution in web but I can't see anything like that. I take the open-source project of this app from GitHub, and there's nothing written about it.
There is provider code:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/models/additionalWeatherData.dart';
import 'package:flutter_weather/models/geocode.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

import '../models/dailyWeather.dart';
import '../models/hourlyWeather.dart';
import '../models/weather.dart';

class WeatherProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String apiKey = '744b94562476e3686d8944d72c0bb1f2';
  late Weather weather;
  late AdditionalWeatherData additionalWeatherData;
  LatLng? currentLocation;
  List<HourlyWeather> hourlyWeather = [];
  List<DailyWeather> dailyWeather = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isRequestError = false;
  bool isSearchError = false;
  bool isLocationserviceEnabled = false;
  LocationPermission? locationPermission;
  bool isCelsius = true;

  String get measurementUnit => isCelsius ? '°C' : '°F';

  Future<Position?> requestLocation(BuildContext context) async {
    isLocationserviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    notifyListeners();

    if (!isLocationserviceEnabled) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Location service disabled')),
      );
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    locationPermission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      locationPermission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Permission denied'),
        ));
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, Please enable manually from app settings',
        ),
      ));
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  Future<void> getWeatherData(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool notify = false,
  }) async {
    isLoading = true;
    isRequestError = false;
    isSearchError = false;
    if (notify) notifyListeners();

    Position? locData = await requestLocation(context);

    if (locData == null) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }

    try {
      currentLocation = LatLng(locData.latitude, locData.longitude);
      await getCurrentWeather(currentLocation!);
      await getDailyWeather(currentLocation!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      isRequestError = true;
    } finally {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentWeather(LatLng location) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&units=metric&appid=$apiKey',
    );
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      weather = Weather.fromJson(extractedData);
      print('Fetched Weather for: ${weather.city}/${weather.countryCode}');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      isLoading = false;
      this.isRequestError = true;
    }
  }

  Future<void> getDailyWeather(LatLng location) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    Uri dailyUrl = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&units=metric&exclude=minutely,current&appid=$apiKey',
    );
    try {
      final response = await http.get(dailyUrl);
      final dailyData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      additionalWeatherData = AdditionalWeatherData.fromJson(dailyData);
      List dailyList = dailyData['daily'];
      List hourlyList = dailyData['hourly'];
      hourlyWeather = hourlyList
          .map((item) => HourlyWeather.fromJson(item))
          .toList()
          .take(24)
          .toList();
      dailyWeather =
          dailyList.map((item) => DailyWeather.fromDailyJson(item)).toList();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      isLoading = false;
      this.isRequestError = true;
    }
  }

  Future<GeocodeData?> locationToLatLng(String location) async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=$location&limit=5&appid=$apiKey',
      );
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) return null;
      return GeocodeData.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body)[0] as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> searchWeather(String location) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    isRequestError = false;
    print('search');
    try {
      GeocodeData? geocodeData;
      geocodeData = await locationToLatLng(location);
      if (geocodeData == null) throw Exception('Unable to Find Location');
      await getCurrentWeather(geocodeData.latLng);
      await getDailyWeather(geocodeData.latLng);
      // replace location name with data from geocode
      // because data from certain lat long might return local area name
      weather.city = geocodeData.name;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      isSearchError = true;
    } finally {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void switchTempUnit() {
    isCelsius = !isCelsius;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}



make sure that final http.Response response = await http.get(url); response successfully got the data, if not recheck the url. finally if all works, what is the response, is it a list of Map, noticed that you are getting response.body[0].

It would help to know which line the error is happening, but without that detail, we can still find potential sources of the problem.
It looks like there are two values in the provided code sample that are the receiver of a call to the [] operator, dailyData and jsonDecode(response.body)[0] as Map<String, dynamic>.
dailyData is initialized as:
final dailyData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
We know that dailyData cannot be null because if json.decode(response.body) were null in this line, the cast to a Map (... as Map<String, dynamic>) would have thrown a different exception, so the issue must lie in the other usage of []: jsonDecode(response.body)[0] as Map<String, dynamic>
The problem in this instance is that you are calling [] on the result of a call to jsonDecode() which is a dynamic value, and could be null, not necessarily something supporting the [] operator.
It would be a good idea for you to first check the value of json.decode(response.body) prior to using the [] operator to make sure it looks like what you're expecting (looks like either a List or Map<int, something>) instead of null
